# limit question - $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(f(x))=c$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can i say that if  $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=b$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow b}g(x)=c$
then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(f(x))=c$ ?

I don't think so but don't know how to prove it.

Thanks.

Comment: This is only true if $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $g$ is continuous at $b$,

Comment: can you give an example when it's not true?

Comment: maybe something with trig function but i don't have a specific idea.

Comment: I think I'm wrong.  Let me think about this for a bit and get back to you.

Comment: no problem just notice that both sides of the $a$ and $b$ are exist by the question.

Comment: You are almost right, but you need an extra condition on $f$. You must ensure that $f(x) \neq b$ when $x \to a$. In more technical language there must be neighborhood of $a$ of type $I = (a - h, a + h)$ such that $f(x) \neq b$ whenever $x \in I, x \neq a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the functions $g(x)=0$ if $x \neq 0$ and $g(0) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$. Then all limits do exists but do not happens what the OP expected.

Comment: It depends on your definition of a limit. Some authors define limits on punctured neighborhood (which seems to be your case), some others don't…

Comment: i can't understand how this is a counterexample.

Comment: @user225185 Well, $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} g(x) = 0$, right?  And $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$, right?  But for all $x$, $f(x) = 0$, so for all $x$, $g(f(x)) = g(0) = 1$.  This means $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} g(f(x)) = \lim \limits_{x \to 0} 1 = 1$, and $1 \neq \lim \limits_{x \to 0} g(x)$, so this disproves the conclusion in your question.

Comment: thanks for improving the explanation of my example.